# Circles with a diameter

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, coordinate-systems, oxyplot

I have an OxyPlot that looks like this so far:

[image]

But I would like to create circles with a hole in the middle and I can give the circles a diameter, how big these should be.

[image]

Do not let the picture irritate you, the circles should be the same size

In the end it should look like this. With circles the holes are in the middle and have a certain diameter.

**XAML**

```
<oxy:Plot x:Name="oxyPlot" Title="{Binding Title}" Height="279" Canvas.Left="259" Canvas.Top="29" Width="344" Background="#FFD1CFD0">
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" MinimumPadding="0.1" MaximumPadding="0.1"/>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" MinimumPadding="0.1" MaximumPadding="0.1"/>
    </oxy:Plot.Axes>
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries x:Name="ls" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" LineStyle="None"  MarkerType="Circle" MarkerSize="5" MarkerFill="Black"/>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a combination of these properties on you LineSeries:

```
MarkerStroke="Red" 
MarkerType="Circle" 
MarkerStrokeThickness="3" 
MarkerSize="5" 
MarkerFill="Transparent"
```

`MarkerSize` determines the radius, and `MarkerStrokeThickness` determines the thickness of the outer line. Note that in order to get an empty circle at the middle, `MarkerStrokeThickness` should be less than `MarkerSize`. `MarkerFill` determines the color of the inner circle and `MarkerStroke` determines the color of the border.

More complex shapes can be created by `MarkerType="Custom"` and setting `MarkerOutline` property.

**In Code**

```
        ls.MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle;
        ls.MarkerFill = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Transparent;
        ls.MarkerStroke = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red;
        ls.MarkerSize = 40;
        ls.MarkerStrokeThickness = 3;
```

Comment: I would have a short question. How can I change the marker type in the code **not** in XAML? Unfortunately, `oxyPlot.MarkerTyp` does not go. How do I have to do it?

Comment: must be sth like this: ls.MarkerType = MarkerTypes.Circle;

Comment: I found it out unfortunately only for MarkerType. Unfortunately, I still lack MarkerFill and the rest. Do you have an idea? `ls.MarkerType = MarkerType.Square;`

Comment: @GabelUndMesser see the edit of the answer. Hope it helps.